# ALFA(XACML) language documentation or tutorials

Tags: authorization, xacml, abac, alfa

I'm trying to find some resources that I could use to learn ALFA language, googling doesn't seem to help me on this one, or I'm asking wrong questions. Could you recommend me some at least decent resources?

Answer (score 0):

I'll be happy to help (as one of the authors of the spec). Here are some useful links:

- The [ALFA wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ALFA_(XACML)): I personally try to add as many examples of ALFA there to help others.
- An [introduction to the ALFA Plugin for Eclipse](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OVY009YZMoQ)
- A beginner's guide to XACML & ALFA - with YouTube videos

  - [Part I](https://www.axiomatics.com/resources/tutorial-a-beginners-guide-to-xacml-part-1/)
  - [Part II](https://www.axiomatics.com/resources/tutorial-a-beginers-guide-to-xacml-part-2-getting-started-with-alfa/)
  - [Part III](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=czFBYGyHVdg)
- Webinars

  - [Boot Camp: ABAC and XACML made easy - Using ALFA to write fine grained authorization policies](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NjTG6qul7Zc)

### Update February 2024

We've launched our [alfa.guide](https://alfa.guide) site to help implementors. Check it out!